# which is faster assigning a number to the variable or changing the value of that variable either by adding or subtracting some number?

Tags: c, operators

which is faster among the following?

`int a = 10 \\initialisation`

I want to change the value of a to 11 and I can do this in two ways as follows

1.`a = 11`

or

2.`a += 1`

which is faster 1 or 2 and btw I'm using C language for this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Assignment and increment have different semantic meaning, so comparing them seems a bit weird...

Comment: Unless you're doing that millions of times it is irrelevant. Write the code that feels more natural (`a = 11;`).

Comment: @pmg that's not what I asked.

Comment: It depends on the variable, the compiler and the target system. If you really need to use the faster variant, you need to compile both and look at the resulting machine code. If your target uses pipelines and/or caches, it gets difficult.

Comment: Asking "which is faster" makes no sense without defining "fast", without giving the context (platform, workload, memory load, ...) and without benchmarking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing the modification of *a* affect the stack rather than *a* is only supported by a register :

- `a = 11` is a simple write, and on a lot of CPU the CPU executes the next instruction(s) before the write in memory is finished (under condition of memory access(es) of course)
- `a +=1` need first to read the value then when it is done to increment it then to write the new value, all of that even through a single assembler instruction. This needs more time than a write except if the CPU is able to parallelize the read+increment+write with the next instruction(s).

If the use of *a* optimized to be only supported by a register all depends on the length of the instruction, to increment a register can need less bytes than to set a value and be faster then, mainly when the assigned value is large.

Whatever the case the difference of time is almost nothing, to have a source code readable and robust is more important

- `a = 11` is both readable and robust
- `a += 1` is only right when *a* already values 10 and this is both less readable (it is needed to look before to guess *a* will value 11) and less robust (if a change is done before *a* may not value 10 as expected)